# Laravel/PHP/HHVM error log showing line number -1

Tags: php, laravel, hhvm, error-log

I'm using Laravel 5.4, php 5.5.9 and HHVM 3.15.3
I'm getting error logs, but showing line number is -1, like:

> Fatal error: Class undefined: App\Http\Controllers\XXXX in XXXX/XXXXController.php on line -1

Hoping to get some help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: you need to provide your code, routes, Controllers,...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably trying to use a class you forgot to import at the top. Hard to tell with no code though.

Comment: Yes, I purposefully missed the Import part to show the example. Here main problem is I'm not getting the line number of error to debug.